# How to call array parameter in method()?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    static class Solution {
        public int solution(int[] array, int height) {
            int answer = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] > height) {
                    answer++;
                }
            }

            return answer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solution());
    }
}
```

I want to add some numbers in solution(), but how should I write numbers properly so I can see the answer; the result?

Comment: You must pass 2 parameters to your solution call: an array and an integer. What is the question exactly?

Comment: `int[] someArray = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 30, 40}; int someHeight = 10; System.out.println(solution(someArray, someHeight));`

Comment: I want to know what i should write in solution() of 'System.out.println(solution());' to see the return value

Answer (score 0):

Your function requires two parameters - an array of numbers and a number.
So, you simply need to pass them. Something like that would do:

```
System.out.println(new Solution().solution(new int[]{1,2,30,4,555}, 10));
```